# How to set the right data type block size for encryption

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm trying to encrypt some plain text with the use of a private and public key.

I'm using python and this is what I'm working with to start.

```
from hashlib import md5
from base64 import b64decode
from base64 import b64encode
from Crypto import Random

BLOCK_SIZE = 16  # Bytes
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * \
                str(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]


class AESCipher:
    """
    Usage:
        c = AESCipher('password').encrypt('message')
        m = AESCipher('password').decrypt(c)
    Tested under Python 3 and PyCrypto 2.6.1.
    """

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = md5(key.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:])).decode('utf8')


##
# MAIN
# Just a test.
msg = input('Message...: ')
pwd = input('Password..: ')

c = AESCipher(pwd).encrypt(msg.encode('utf8'))
m = AESCipher(pwd).decrypt(c)

# print('Ciphertext:', AESCipher(pwd).encrypt(msg.encode('utf8')))
```

I'm getting this error in Pycharm

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   ".../PycharmProjects/test/App.py", line 97, in 
>       c = AESCipher(pwd).encrypt(msg.encode('utf8'))

File ".../PycharmProjects/test/App.py", line 79, in encrypt

> ```
> raw = pad(raw)   File ".../PycharmProjects/test/App.py", line 63, in <lambda>
> str(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
> ```

How do I change the block padding type from str to byte?

Comment: If you're using PyCryptodome you can find padding functions in [`Crypto.Util.Padding`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module). Also, a `lambda` is an anonymous function, if you have to name it then it's best to use a normal function - see [PEP8, programming recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to slightly modify your padding function:

```
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * \
                chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE).encode()
```

note the `chr` instead of `str` and that the string then needs to encoded to `bytes`.

or maybe better:

```
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * \
                bytes((BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE, ))
```

Comment: Im getting the same kind of error.

 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py", line 234, in c_uint8_ptr
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code

Comment: can not reproduce... but it looks as if you did not convert all of your `str` insances to `bytes`. without a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem i can't help.